# Cant select option of dropdown in selenium

Tags: java, jquery, selenium, drop-down-menu

I am displaying a dropdown for user to select after i click signup tab. But using selenium i am not able to select any option.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("signup")).click();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,15); 
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
Select drop = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("user_type_select")));
drop.selectByIndex(2);
```

The signup tab appears but the dropdown is not selected. Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Implicit wait is for the element to be present, but does not guarantee clickability or certain behaviours. Without the page you are trying to automate, it's hard to tell - e.g. [jqueryui.selectmenu](https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/) hides the original 'select` - present but never visible - and replaces it by a set of nodes with event handlers which mocks a select, so you [may have troubles automating it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28947955/how-to-automate-jqueryui-selectmenu-with-selenium-web-driver-selenium-ide). Other js UI libs may present different problems.

Comment: @Amarendra, any stacktrace please?

Answer (score 0):

can you sure the select is ready after 10s?
try this:

```
waiter.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("user_type_select")));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to wait for the elements to load and javascript to execute. At the end point javascript is the last action completed by a webpage, so check for the wait time of it. Sample code below.

```
wait.equals((((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete")));
```